# How to pick up only one row per field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT userid, message, usergroup 
FROM   mybb_myprofilecomments, mybb_users
WHERE  userid = uid
AND    usergroup NOT IN (5,7)
AND    approved = 1
AND    isprivate = 0
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Please assume that `uid, usergroup` are fields in `mybb_users table`, and `userid, message` are fields in `mybb_myprofilecomments`.

It gives following:

[image]

But instead of having 2 rows for userid "6551", I want one of 2 rows (older one at 3rd row in terms of time) gets replaced with a row with another userid that is not listed here.

How can I do this?
Thank you very much.